# Jmeter: Scenario to test 5 users with ramp up 1 hour to trigger 10 thousand requests

Tags: jmeter

Jmeter: We have a scenario where 5 users should trigger 10 thousand requests in 1 hour, to achieve this below configurations have been done.

1. Thread group - users - 5; ramp up - 3600 (secs); loop count - 1
2. Loop controller value: 10000
3. Request is under this Loop Controller

When executed the above scenario, Jmeter is executing/triggering 5 users in 1 second only.

Are these configurations correct to achieve our scenario load testing output.

Please suggest and guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration is a little bit incorrect. In your setup

1. JMeter will start with one user which will execute 10 000 requests as fast as it can
2. In 12 minutes another user will start and execute 10 000 requests as fast as it can
3. In 12 minutes another user will start and execute 10 000 requests as fast as it can
4. etc.

You will not get 10 000 requests evenly distributed for 1 hour, instead you will have 50 000 requests in "spikes"

Instead I would suggest the following configuration:

- Thread Group (Number of Users: 5, Ramp-Up Period : 1, Loop Count: Forever, Duration: 3600)

  [image]

  - Request

    - [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) with Target Throughput: `166.6666666667`

      [image]

      Constant Throughput Timer will limit JMeter to the desired rate which will give you 10 000 requests in hour (assuming your application will be able to handle the requests fast enough)

---

In the majority of cases it's easier to use custom Thread Groups such as [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/). It's easier to configure as it provides a graph demonstrating anticipated virtual users behaviour.

[image]

You can install custom thread groups using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed information. Just small query so Target Throughput: 166.6666666667 formula is (10000/60 mints) which gives 166 value. Our one more scenario is, 1,00,000 requests per hour per 1 user so Target Throughput should be: 1666.666666667 (1,00,000/60) and the duration would remain 3600 with users 1. Please suggest. And thanks a lot for guidance.

Comment: It should be sufficient to change `Calculate Throughput Based On` to `this thread only`

Comment: Thanks for confirming, however when ran for 1 hour (1,00,000 requests, Target Throughput -  1670 requests per minute) , the execution got stopped after 1 hour and the requests triggered are 67,000 only. It could not complete 1,00,000 and stopped the execution. Please guide if doing something wrong here.

Comment: You might need to increase the number of threads (virtual users) in the Thread Group as Constant Throughput Timer can only **pause** the requests in order to **limit** JMeter to the specified throughput. As an alternative you can try [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin) and [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) combination, they can be connected via [feedback function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/#Use-With-Throughput-Shaping-Timer-Feedback-Function)

Comment: So JMeter will kick off extra threads if current amount is not enough in order to conduct the required load

Comment: Thanks Sir, however when followed all the steps as suggested above for scenario: 1 user, 1 hours duration, loop count of 10000, with constant throughput of 166.66 per minute. The execution is ended after 1 hour but the total number of requests Jmeter could generate only 900. The assumption was Jmeter would trigger and reach 10000 requests but it stopped after 1 hour with only 900 requests. Please suggest if we are going anything wrong here.